# I get error in layout page of visual studio 2019 which is the error indicates @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, layout

---

## Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I try update NuGet package, change styleBundle with Bundle in App_Start Folder BundleConfig.cs  also run installer and modify it. I expect solution please help me

Answer (score 0):

the error show me in layout page @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") but the error came because of improper use of Session like this
<img src=@Session["profile"].ToString()
alt="Profile" class="rounded-circle">
after change this code the error fixed